# android: save error state on change orientation

Tags: android, orientation, android-edittext, savestate

I make a login form with dynamic field validation. I have 3 fields username, email & password & all of these field are required. When field length = 0, I set error

```
editText.setError( getText(R.string.cannot_be_blank) );
```

and this code works fine, but when I change the orientation, all the errors disappear
How to save error state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the orientation is changed the framework will recreate the Activity by calling `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. Before the switch in orientation the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` method will be called if it is overridden in your Activity.

You can save the state of your errors in the Bundle passed into the `onSaveInstanceState` method. This bundle is passed to your `onCreate()` method as the `savedInstanceState` Bundle.

Therefore you need to override the `onSaveInstanceState` method in your Activity as follows (saving the state of your errors):

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("errorOccurred", errorState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Then in your `onCreate` method check if the `savedInstateState` Bundle is null or not. If not, you can retrieve the values out of it with the following code:

```
boolean errorOccurred = false;  
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    errorOccurred = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("errorOccurred"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the orientation is changed the Android framework destroys the Activity and then creates a new one for the new orientation.   So all your state is lost.

Use SharedPreferences to store and restore your state and TextEdit values.

Comment: for an error message based on the TextEdit value it is better to re-evaluate in onResume than to save the state...

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you turn the device is that your `Activity` runs through its lifecycle in order to deal with the fact that the layout must change from portrait to landscape.

You should take a look at the developer docs on how to [Handle Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).